# Enqueue Stylesheet on the front end and in the block editor Conditionally

Tags: css, block-editor, wp-enqueue-style, conditional-content

How would you include a `stylesheet` in both the `block-editor` and on the `front-end` if the page meets certain criteria?

In this case I want to include a `stylesheet` called `homepage.css` if the page is the home page only. I therefore did this:

```
 add_action('enqueue_block_assets', function () {
   if(is_front_page()){
     wp_enqueue_style(
       'homepage-stylesheet',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/homepage.css',
     );
   }
});
```

Whilst the code works on the `front-end` it does not in the `block-editor` as it appears that `is_front_page()` cannot be determined until the page is rendered.

How would you go about this?

Comment: it would be easier to use the `.home` rule and take advantage of the body classes WP adds to help with this. Otherwise what you want is impossible if you ever plan to use the template or site editors as there's no way to know from PHP since the user can click into another template and it would be broken

Comment: @TomJNowell I see you point but its about loading fewer resources, or more accurately, only relevant resources. I can think of a number of ways to do this but I just thought that something a simple as this would be included in the code base.

Comment: in the strictest sense nothing prevents you doing this using the same strategy on the frontend, just don't expect it to work on the backend as it's a React/JS application, `enqueue_block_assets` may not be the ideal action to do that on, and there are definitely disadvantages to this approach and additional complexity, it's not the silver bullet it first appears to be

Comment: @TomJNowell . I've implemented a it using the template slug as the identifier and it works perfectly on the front end and the block editor with every single stylesheet. I'm yet to find the problem you mention in any case.

Comment: open the site editor on a page that isn't the homepage, then navigate to the homepage within the site editor and you'll see that the `homepage.css` file is not loaded. Similarly load the site editor on the homepage and navigate to any other template or page and you'll see that the rules in `homepage.css` are still applied. Note that this is not a problem if you use `.home` selectors, even if you use them in a conditionally loaded file, and it isn't a problem if your conditional loading only happens on the frontend

Comment: @TomJNowell I don't consider the site editor paticlarly helpful so I have not encountered this but for editing post and pages in the block editor, this issue is not present. Combining this with a unique selector is a wise precaution however. In this case of using it with the template slug concept this would be a .page-template-homepage selector.

Comment: as an aside, you could register a "homepage" block style on a group block to selectively apply homepage styling to everything inside it, so that you can have sections of a page without styling the entire page and place it anywhere you want across the entire site

Comment: Now that's a very good idea. I could actually call it a custom-asset block and use it for any such use case.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done. @TomJNowell does point out the potential for a problem with this solution in the comments to the question but I cannot replicate that problem in any test.

In this example I locked on to the template slug. Therefore for this to work instead of using is_front_page() or similar, create a template called homepage and use it only for the homepage. Then do the same for any other pages you want to have a custom stylesheet.

```
add_action('enqueue_block_assets', function () {

  global $post; 

  $template = get_page_template_slug($post->ID);

  wp_enqueue_style(
    $template . '-template-styles',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/' . $template . '.css',
  ); 

});
```